# Загрузка картинок через асинхронные коллбэки в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Необходимо асинхронно загрузить картинку из папки на компьютере. В коде предусмотрена возможность: если картинка не загружается, в консоль должна выбрасываться ошибка. Но в приведенном мною коде данный

```
if (!onerr) {
    err = null;
} else {
    err = 'Error loading image'; 
}
```

не срабатывает если я указываю имя не существующей картинки, а при указании правильного имени картинка грузится. Как можно исправить код чтоб данная ошибка появлялась в консоли при указании не существующей картинки? Вот код:

```
function loadImage(url, callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        let image = document.createElement('img');
        image.src = url;
        
        let err;
        let onerr = image.addEventListener('error', function() {
            console.log('Error loading image'); // текст ошибки
        });

        if (!onerr) {
            err = null;
        } else {
            err = 'Error loading image'; 
        }
        
        callback(image, err);
    }, 1000);
}

loadImage('/home/artemiy/JS/5.jpeg', function(image, err) {
    if (!err) {
        document.body.append(image);
    } else {
        console.log('Произошла ошибка: ' + err);
    }
});
```

Comment: Ваш `onerr` всегда **undefined**, поэтому ошибки вы никогда не получите в колбэке. С другой стороны, вы должны были получить ошибку из самого листнера.

Comment: Что это за бредятина? Chatgpt писал что ли?

Comment: @Jour Вы не туда отправляете. `try catch` тут не поможет. Смотреть надо на [Загрузку ресурсов](https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-onerror). Ну и в целом понимать, что обработчики событий срабатывают в момент самих событий, а не в момент их объявления. З.Ы. Про ересь писал не я, однако согласен, код не логичен и избыточен.

Comment: вы должны были получить ошибку из самого листнера. Этот совет оказался правильным. Благодарю за совет.